# Many hundreds more students

Tags: numbers

Is [*many hundreds more  students*](https://languagelog.ldc.upenn.edu/nll/?p=50257#comments) grammatically correct? I'm wondering about the lack of the preposition **of** and what PoS are *hundreds* and *more*.

Otherwise, where would **of** be placed?

I am comparing the phrase with the simpler *hundreds **of** students.*

HUNDRED: https://www.oed.com/oed2/00109312

MORE: https://www.oed.com/oed2/00151364

Comment: Hundreds of students, many hundreds of students. // More students, hundreds more students, many hundreds more students. You can check using Google ngrams (alongside that aren't acceptable, such as 'many hundreds more of students').

Comment: @EdwinAshworth What PoS are _hundreds_ and _more_ in **hundreds more students**?

Comment: @EdwinAshworth On the other hand, *(many) hundreds more of **the** students* is acceptable, do you agree?

Comment: I'd go with numerical pre-quantifier and quantifier, though CGEL won't agree.

Comment: @linguisticturn Yes. But now we're into referring back to a known set, which OP doesn't do.

Comment: I would say it's idiomatic.

Comment: @HotLicks Not sure how you use _idiomatic_, but _hundreds fewer (students) came_ is also possible.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth can't find that terminology in academic literature, which of the uses in OED would that be? https://www.oed.com/oed2/00109312

Comment: I'd consider OED inaccurate in its POS tagging. See [John Lawler's, and Matt E. Эллен's answer and my comment here](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/504264/is-there-a-word-for-words-like-dozen-score-gross-that-refer-to-specific/504366#504366) and 'Numerals are distinguished from other quantifiers by the fact that they designate a specific number. Examples are words such as five, ten, fifty, one hundred, etc. They may or may not be treated as a distinct part of speech' at [Wikipedia, §1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numeral_(linguistics)).

Comment: @EdwinAshworth still, _A/one hundred more students_ or _five more students_
but NOT _*Five**s** more students_ (versus _the students arrived in (the?) hundreds_ or _in fives_)

Comment: what is the analysis of the phrase using constituent brackets?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is acceptable. Here are some attested examples of similar usage:

> ***Many hundreds more rebels** were dead now.*
> *If there were any delay, **many thousands more people** would die.*
> *The Germans had expended seventeen trainloads of ammunition and **many thousands more men**.*
> <sup>All from *British National Corpus* [(BNC)](https://www.english-corpora.org/bnc/)</sup>
>
> *…their own well-trained, well-armed ground troops over the **many thousands more lives** of the defenseless victims of these perpetrators.*
> <sup>From *Corpus of Contemporary American English* [(COCA)](https://www.english-corpora.org/coca/)</sup>

According to [CGEL](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0521431468) (p. 356), *many* and *more* belong to the lexical category of **determinatives,** and are both **degree determinatives.**

As far as *hundreds,* this is a cardinal numeral. Since it is here inflected for grammatical number, it is actually a noun. As CGEL says (p. 385),

> The cardinal numerals are primarily determinatives but they have a secondary use in which they inflect for number and hence belong in the noun category: *They set off in **threes**/enrolled in their **hundreds**.* In practice, only low or round numerals are used in this way.

Next, I would like to argue that *many hundreds more* is a constituent, i.e. that we have the following constituent structure:

*[ [many hundreds more] students]*.

(I will deal with the internal structure of *many hundreds more* below.)

Constituency analysis is sometimes quite difficult and there can be pitfalls. I don't claim that the arguments I'm about to present are irrefutable, but I hope that they will suffice unless and until someone presents a positive argument that this is not the right constituent structure.

First, we have argument from coordination; *in general,* only constituents can be coordinated:

***many hundreds more** or **many hundreds fewer** students*

Yes, there are exceptions, and, without further analysis, argument from coordination is usually not sufficient.

But here is a second argument: the **fragment answers** test. Normally, only a constituent can answer a question, while retaining the meaning of the original sentence (see e.g. [here](https://people.umass.edu/nconstan/201/Constituency%20Tests.pdf)):

*Many hundreds more students arrived.* -> Q: *How many students arrived?* A: *Many hundreds more.*

Again, these are not irrefutable arguments, but I hope they will do for now.

Assuming that *many hundreds more* is indeed a constituent, it would function as **determinative phrase** (DP). Here are some other examples of DPs (CGEL, pp. 23, 54, 385, 395, 424, 431, 432):

*almost every/all         too many                                            some/any more

all the more                not every                                              hardly any

at least ten                  more/less/fewer than twenty         considerably/a lot more than fifty

no/a little more          greater than 20 000*

As far as the constituent structure of the DP itself, it would seem to be

*[ [many hundreds] more]*,

with *more* as the head of this DP.

The arguments would again be similar. First, from coordination:

***many hundreds** or **even several thousands** more*

Second, from the fragment answers test:

*Many hundreds more students arrived.* -> Q: *How many more students arrived?* A: *Many hundreds.*

Once we accept that *[ [many hundreds] more]* is the constituent structure of the DP, we look for the head. This is a DP, so the head should be a determinative. This excludes *hundreds*, because, as we said, that is a noun. But *many hundreds* is clearly an NP, with *hundreds* as the head. This means that *many* cannot be the head of *many hundreds more*. Namely, a basic postulate of constituent structure is that it is hierarchical: the ultimate head of a phrase is also the head of all subconstituents of which that head is part. If *many* were the head of *many hundreds more*, the hierarchical postulate would demand that it also be the head of the subconstituent *many hundreds*. But we have just seen that *many* is **not** the head of *many hundreds*; thus, it cannot be the head of *many hundreds more*. This leaves *more* as the only possibility for being the head of *many hundreds more*.

If all this is correct, the full constituent structure is

*[ [ [many hundreds] more ] students]*.

Comment: Thank you so much. Could you compare briefly the analysis of _one hundred civilians and soldiers had been killed and **hundreds more injured**_ ?

Comment: @GJC Sorry, which two things are you asking me to compare? Or are you simply asking for an analysis of *hundreds more injured*?

Comment: **hundreds more injured**.

Comment: @GJC In that sentence, that's not a constituent. What you have in that sentence is **gapping,** a type of ellipsis. The basic form of the sentence is *one hundred civilians and soldiers had been killed and hundreds more **had been** injured.*

Comment: **more** must deserve another analysis instead a determinative

Comment: @GJC In what? In the sentence you just asked about?

Comment: Yes in _hundreds more (had been) injured_